# docker nginx, php what's wrong?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I created nginx server with PHP, but it's not working.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - 127.0.0.1:8080:80
    volumes:
        - ./docs:/docs
        - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    links:
        - php
php:
    image: php:latest
    volumes:
        - ./docs:/docs
```

site.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    server_name php.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /docs;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1   php.local
```

Docker runs in terminal without errors:

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
Starting php_php_1
Starting php_web_1
```

And when I type in browser 127:0:0:1:8080 or php.local:8080 it's refused connection why?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct syntax for Port forwarding

```
    - 127.0.0.1:8080:80
```

Replace it with a simple

```
    - 8080:80
```

The docker-composer IP is not your localhost. To find out your docker-compose IP, you need to call `docker-machine ip default`, (for example, if you are suing OSX) ...read more here https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/

typically the IP is something like `192.168.99.100` so if yo call http://192.168.99.100:8080 , your server on the docker-compose container should be reachable

Comment: I use Fedora. According to tutorials I dont need docker-machine. It should work on localhost ... Call to  http://192.168.99.100:8080 not working.